# Split large csv file and import to postgresql

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Hi,

I m trying to find a solution to a problem that we currently have. We have a CSV file in S3 that contains around 1m lines and I need to read this file and insert in to a postgresql db while I m doing that I need to read only 10000 lines and then insert to db. need to read the next 10000 and do the same until EOF. My solution that I m looking at is  Trigger a lambda function when s3 gets the 1m raw file. This lambda will read 10000 lines and insert the records to db fpr every 10000. Problem with this is my lambda timeout because its taking more than 5mins to do it. Please suggest some solution.

Comment: do you have access to the db via `psql`?

Comment: Yes, I have @jimJones

Comment: Okay, have you tried something like `cat large.csv | psql testdb -c "COPY your_table FROM STDIN WITH DELIMITER ';' CSV HEADER;"`

Comment: @JimJones he is trying to do it from Lambda function and commands are not possible there.

Comment: To split it before: http://burnignorance.com/linux-tips-and-tricks/splitting-a-large-csv-files-into-smaller-files-in-ubuntu/

Comment: @SandeepRandhawa oh I see the issue now. I was considering only `psql` and the old fashioned shell. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

A possible solution is use the seek function (Perl / Python) that handles the file position. 
This function allow you jump directly to a file position and start to read from that.
It's very usefull for read large files.

Comment: Perl is not supported on AWS Lambda.